# Is my question on a one-off game too subjective?

Tags: discussion, appropriateness

I asked [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/312/which-game-for-a-one-off-with-my-group). I even remarked, at the end of it, that it may very well be closed as too subjective.

However, it seems an RPG-oriented Stack Exchange site might differ from others in that subjective is almost the norm.

So my question is: Did I cross a subjective line, or is that question OK?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's OK as long as it's tightly scoped like yours was.  A question of "Which is better, D&D 3e or 4e" should be off topic flame bait, but "What are the pros and cons of A and B for this specific need" seems fair.

Perhaps over time that'll get tiresome, as people will ask the every popular-but-banal "what game would be best for X!" and you get the same 20 goons with their pet games pimping them.

Comment: At cooking.stackexchange.com there is a 'no recipes' rule. However, 'what are the pro's and cons of A and B' is fine. 'What would be best' is probably off-limits, but 'what overarching principles / mechanics would work well for X' probably is in-bounds. (Barring obvious lazyness and other obvious disqualifiers)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly think we're going to trend more subjective -- it's the nature of the beast. Perl is a bit more defined than the process of roleplaying.

Comment: Yes, this too. RPG is closer to 'personal experience' than the fastest-executing SQL plan.

Answer (score 0):

Even a question like yours is likely to generate interesting answers that may be helpful to other people. A question is only too subjective if it's of *no* interest to other people at all.