# No longer accepting answers from this account

Tags: support, answers

I'm sure this sort of question gets asked a lot, but I've just tried to answer a question and I'm banned? apparently my previous answers where not well received.

The thing is, I've only ever answered 1 question last November, and although not upvoted it wasn't downvoted either, it's just sitting on 0 rep.

I've mostly been idling to be honest but now I can't contribute, and "fixing my answers" as per the suggestion won't help. Is this account just irreversibly ruined for me on this stack?

Comment: If you are having trouble understanding the linked meta: The best thing you can do it edit and then undelete the answers you removed yourself. High % of deleted posts counts against you and is likely what caused your ban.

Comment: OK thanks, that's not covered in the meta, I thought realising I was wrong about a few things and removing them would be fine

Comment: Typically that would be fine but since you have so few answers total, the combined downvotes and deletion is a high percentage of your total answers. Once you get past the ban you can post more answers then deleting shouldn't be an issue. You can answer old questions if want and can find something to add that others haven't mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

Your account is not irreversibly ruined.

You have four answers in total on this site. Three of them were downvoted and removed, two by you and one by others, though you may not recall removing those two. You can view two of them in [your recent deleted answers list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/45442) (this link will work only for you and diamond moderators) and the third one is [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135596).

However, you are only blocked from answering. You are still able to [ask questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Asking good questions will help you earn your way out of your answer ban.

The answer ban is automated and we cannot do anything to lift it ourselves; only you can. The answer ban takes place because your contributions aren't being accepted well and is a suggestion you need to wait and learn how things work first.

I am under the impression that when you try to answer and hit the blocked message, you're given a link to [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) on main meta. If not, there is the link now: I suggest reading through it.

Answer (score 7):

## Writing answers that are backed up

You've got just one [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135017/23024) that's still live with a +4/-1 rating. That's good - but please see the comment that I left on that answer. Based on the one deleted answer I could see on Doppel's post, that seems to be a major issue for why you're being downvoted.

If you [back up](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-rpg-stack-exchange) your answer with either table play experience or by citing official rules, that will go a long way towards improving peoples responses and votes. Linking to unofficial sites, especially without much surrounding support, is generally poorly received.