# Can I get some examples of users assuming a question is asking about D&D 5e when it's explicitly tagged as being for another system/edition?

Tags: discussion, questions, game-systems, dnd-5e, protected-questions

I know this is common, but my google-fu is failing me (particularly since the relevant search field would mostly be in the comment section of deleted answers).

Does anyone have some helpful example questions where users posted an answer assuming a question was for D&D 5e when it was already apparent (from system/edition tags) that it wasn't?

I think Dungeon World gets a lot of this, but anything is fine.  It would be helpful for [supporting my answer on the question "How should question protection be used on RPG.SE?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10116/how-should-question-protection-be-used-on-rpg-se/10147?noredirect=1#comment35304_10147).

Comment: I had one a few weeks ago that I assumed was 5e, but when I asked the OP said "yeah it was 5e, but if you can tell me for 3.5 too that would be good", I know it's only sort of what you are looking for, but that's all I could think of. Not sure what the question was, but I'll try track it down.

Comment: ^Although I guess that is an issue of "guessing the system" whereas your question is more about cases where the system is already known but people still answer otherwise.

Comment: To clarify per the above: Are you looking specifically for, e.g., questions without a system tag that get answers that assume a specific system/edition? Or are you also okay with pointing to answers where the question was already clearly tagged with a different system than the one the answer was for?

Comment: @V2Blast If not the former, it would be great to have a thread tracking answers like that. It seems like there is constant discussion about "Don't Guess" but not a lot of evidence.

Comment: @V2Blast I am *only* interested in examples where an answer ignores an already-present system tag. This isn't about the 'don't guess' policy, or rather not directly, it's about when users don't even check and just assume the question is asking about X system (that X is *oftest* whatever the most recent version of D&D was at the time, but not always)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I linked a couple in one of my answers [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9815/19405) on one of the iterations of the "don't guess the system" question. One was a Dungeon World question people mistook for D&D 5E, another was a Genesys question people mistook for D&D 5E. People, plural.

They were both system-tagged at the time, as was [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/172271/is-there-a-cost-for-donning-or-doffing-a-shield-and-armor-during-combat) question about changing armor during combat for 13th Age, which was mistaken for D&D 5E.

Comment: Our Fate questions also have a few answers like this among them—some people assume the question is about D&D despite the question indicating it's about Fate. Sometimes they recognise it's about Fate, but they don't know what Fate is like, so they give bad advice based on an incorrect assumption that Fate works like the systems they're more familiar with. It is hard to dig these up though, the overall % of Fate questions that got answers like these is relatively small.

Answer (score 4):

A curious point of error can be the WoD/CoD mismatch, where players might assume the two share more rules than they do - and give advice based on the wrong system. Without pointing a finger, I have seen this at least twice.