# How to ask a question when you don't know the english name and references of a spell?

Tags: discussion, questions, language

I have a question about a spell in Deadland Reloaded.
But I'm french and every book I have about it are in french. I have hard time find the english translation of many point. Making it hard to ask about.

I actually have a question about a skill that allow a mad scientist to craft one object once per day. It has any spell in it and half of his mana point.

This is an exemple for a more genereral issue.

How to ask about a skill/spell you do not know the name?

For me the choice are:

- Making global description of the thing I can't name.
- Let some blank or `[X]` in the question.
- Making a poor<sup>*</sup> question about "what is the name of the spell that"
- Directly asking for help in comment, in question.

---

<sup>*, By my standart</sup>

Comment: The Edge you're talking about in Deadlands is Gadgeteer - that should help with your specific question, but I don't know about the more general issue you're talking about

Comment: I think this is a pretty helpful thing for us to cover for the general case. :) Thanks for asking this.

Comment: I had an edit to make it less specific.  Showing the choice I came up with trying to post question.

Comment: Keep it specific, that's a fine & helpful way to handle it. The stack works best when people are specific about their issue.

Comment: I am not on RPG.SE often, but maybe a Sandbox-Post would help. [Here is an example](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/would-this-question-about-combat-be-closed-as-too-broad-or-subjective) of a user asking for help with his specific question. If you always post on Meta first people can help you with such things.

Answer (score 16):

Ask on the chat for the English name, then you can post your question with the correct terms. That's usually what I do when I have questions that are, or so I think, too precise to be used by someone else.

If you can't access the chat or if nobody is able to help you there, make a question about the English name. It may be poor quality in your standards but it is a valid question.

Answer (score 7):

Just explain in your question.  Say something like "I am asking about the skill which is referred to as 'pelear' in my Spanish copy of the D&D books (I am unable to find the correct English game term)" etc etc.

Comment: Would it be good to edit the question to include the English name later? I'm certain someone would add it to the question in a comment.

Comment: As long as it doesn't change the meaning of the question, yes.  So for "how does 'xyncht' interact with 'yncht'?" It'd be appropriate to translate those later.  But for "what is the English term for 'xyncht'?" That would be uncalled for.