# We have better advice for answerers in our "On topic" page than our "How to answer" page

Tags: support, answers

Our Help page ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has some lovely site-specific advice for answerers under the heading *When replying to questions, be aware of our site guidelines*:

> - Not everything here has an objectively correct answer, but subjective answers should be backed up with real play experience. See the blog post [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for how to answer subjective questions on Stack Exchange.
> - There are many different tastes in games and different kinds of playstyle. All styles are welcome here, but attacking others' styles as wrong is not. As a rule, answer questions in the style they were asked - telling someone "they are playing wrong" is usually unwelcome and not constructive.
> - Comments are for asking for clarification or providing constructive feedback on answers and should not be long discussion threads; comments are considered temporary and will be cleaned up by mods. If you have a major point to make, write your own answer and let people vote on it. Comment warring will not be tolerated.

The Help page ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) mentions none of this. So far as I can tell, it doesn't have *any* site-specific advice at all. This seems... non-ideal and easily remedied.

Can we please add our excellent advice to answerers to the page for advice to answerers? And while we're doing that, can we [add a link](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3204/4398) to our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post on [subjective-questions](/questions/tagged/subjective-questions)? We've got some good site-specific advice available for subjective answering, and I know *I* struggled with translating the GS/BS blog into actionable guidelines for RPG.SE on my own (especially since "Back it up!" is now a dead link).

Comment: FYI, the On Topic help page is the one and only thing we (specifically the diamond mods) can edit. The rest is controlled by SE staff and identical across every SE site. There's definitely merit in being able to provide site specific advice on those but it's not currently a thing we can do.

Comment: Ahah. [has a sad]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We can edit the On Topic page, but sadly we can't edit the How to Answer page or other core help centre pages.

Comment: [sad] Can we at least add a link to the site-specific guidance for subjective questions to the On Topic page?

Comment: I think I asked brian about this 2 years ago and he said the same thing basically that those pages were set and from main SE.