# Should we add the citation requirements to our Tour?

Tags: discussion, tour

Looking at the tour, I realized (after reading a comment), that our Tour doesn't include best practices and requirements for how to answer a question that includes citations or good subjective/bad subjective information.

Because of that, new users may really get put off by seeing downvotes from those types of answers that don't have that criteria because they never learned that they needed to have it.

It seems like a good idea to include that information in the tour - which may reduce bad subjective or unsupported answers.

Answer (score 6):

Diamond moderators can edit three parts of the tour:

- The summary of what the site is about.
- The sample question the tour uses.
- The “Ask about...” and “Don't ask about...” lists.

Our citation guidelines don't fit into any of these.

There's a lot of information our tour doesn't include; it's just a quick overview of how Stack Exchange Q&A functions for people who are coming from forums or so on. It isn't meant to go into depth on community norms and expectations.

Comment: Well poop. Is there anything we *can* do preemptively or is it just post a comment to new users answers?

Comment: The technology for providing a direct educational neural upload on site registration is still in the works, so until then we just have to teach people the site's practices as they go.

Comment: I'm disappointed in myself - when I saw the notice of this comment I really thought it was from Korvin :)

Comment: @NautArch My telepathy skills are still not up to the task of getting inside of doppel's head and posting.  Obviously, the Great Old One has not blessed me.

Comment: I can't see how this doesn't fit into the last 2 - surely the sample question can have in it "I'm playing [game-system-goes-here]" and the Ask about can say "If you are asking about a particular game, please tell us what it is." even going on to say "Not all RPGs are Dungeons & Dragons"

Answer (score 1):

As a new and eager to participate community member, ***i agree***. 
The system right now is deferring the task of teaching [this](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3204/22566) and other simple concepts to us new members to a reactive rather than proactive process.

I'm sure we can do better.

The system right now forces retroactive editing and therefor discourages newcomers, in my opinion.

Comment: I think what Doppel is saying is that we actually *can't* due to the restrictions of the platform. Which stinks.

Comment: FWIW, the [help] provides an in depth coverage of a lot of that.