# Can/should we include the system tag requirement in our tour?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, game-systems, tour

I may be missing something, but right now, other than by reading this meta, newcomers won't know they should be tagging their system. We have some suggestions on how to address it ([Can our tag-prompt nudge toward including system?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7681/43856) - which was sadly deferred because it seems changing it is hard due to how SE works), but as of now, I don't see anywhere (again: I may be missing it) stating how important it is.

So, can we (easily) change the [tour] page? If we can, is there an appropriate place to include the importance of tagging (or at least stating) the system you are playing somewhere?

If we can't, is there **anywhere** we can easily, accessibly include this information? It keeps to be one of the main reasons I see questions being closed, and I feel we should be able to do better in introducing this concept to new people than having their questions closed, commenting this rule, hoping for their edit and then reopening it.

Comment: I wonder if we can get statistics on the number of questions without a system tag that are closed where the OP hadn't taken the tour...

Comment: aaand it seems we can't https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8949/43856. Welp. But even then, the help center (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) also doesn't have anything on that. Even in the tagging part (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) nowhere the word "system" appears...

Comment: [New ask page: How do we want to use it to help new users specify their system](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9822)" and "[Can we color system tags to emphasize that they're different and more meaningful](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8702)" and "[Make it possible for certain tags (like game tags) to always appear first](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8366)" and "[Could we have a separate close reason for missing system tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7333)" and "[Can the system tag policy be stated to askers in advance](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9985)"

Comment: @Medix2 that's... a fair point. But at least we could direct them to a more obvious place than a two years old meta question which isn't exactly easy to find. From the meta posts you linked, if any of these were actually implemented, maybe they are only for new users. For me, when I go to the Ask a question page, there's nothing of sorts.

Comment: @HellSaint They aren't actually implemented (were they, it should change to [status-completed]), but do note the system for sending things in for potential implementation is in a bit of [a trial period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/681403) and the team handling them is quite reduced in size atm.

Comment: More to the point, a lot querents only take the tour once we point it out to them, and many not even then, and that's after they've posted that first question (which is usually the only one with a problem), so I'm not sure the tour would be a *high* priority, but it might be nice to also include it. I personally think adding it to the ask page would be better (I would, if you look at Medix's first link) which we also have a *explicit* encouragement to ask for changes to to help new users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you found in comments, [there's only three places we can edit in the tour](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8949/1204): the blurb at the start, the sample question, and the on-topic/off-topic lists. This doesn't fit into any of those.

I'll caveat this by bringing to attention that this isn't about tags per se, it's just about having system information. Expressing that in a title or the body is just as good. We can add the tag subsequently ourselves as long as they tell us the system they're using *somewhere*. (This isn't even about how much information counts as guessing, I just mean saying “I'm playing D&D 5e” in the question title or body is just as good as having the [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) tag on the question.)

As part of making progress on this issue, we should be careful we don't over-focus on one part of it (tags) lest we lose sight of the forest for the one tree we're focusing on. For example, if we have features that guide people to state their system inside the question body instead, those would be extremely useful for helping us make progress on the issue.

(I say this [slightly lamenting that I over-focused on tags](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9986/1204) recently as well. Despite the way that other question puts it, we don't have a system tag policy—we just have a “say what game you're playing” policy.)

Comment: Yeah I agree that we just need the system to be said. But usually what I see happening is that then someone removes the system *from the body* and puts it in the tag, lol. Anyway, this *seems* to be one of the main reasons questions get closed around here and I was hoping we could have a **proactive** way of informing the users about the policy rather than the *reactive* that we do now - which is IMO very inefficient in terms of manpower haha

Comment: @HellSaint Oh, yeah, folks will often do that. It's not necessarily the best practice for us to be responding that way (we _could_ just leave the info in the body and add the tag) but it's still enough that the person says it there in the first place.