# Should we add a definition of a good answer to the tour?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, tour

New users often post uncomplete/chatty answers. Here's a typical comment to such an answer:

> Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get the chance. It's important to note that we're not a forum and we don't do discussion; if you post as an answer, you should directly answer the question that was asked.

However, the tour doesn't have a distinctive guide for answering. It is focused on asking questions:

> #### Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
>
> Ask about...
>
> Don't ask about...

Should we add criteria for an acceptable answer to the tour? Or should we just send new posters to [the help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) instead of the tour?

Comment: Related: [Should we add the citation requirements to our Tour?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8948) 
Also from MSE: [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/681403)

Answer (score 5):

We can't modify the tour that way without developer intervention.

Only three parts of the tour are editable by diamond moderators:

- The blurb at the top—we can change its text. That's the paragraph starting with “RPG Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for...”
- The example question shown in the first section can be swapped for any other.
- The on/off topic list can be edited. These are just bulleted lists like I'm writing now.

This information doesn't fit into any of those groups. The rest is baked in and can't be changed except by Stack Exchange developers specifically modifying the tour to enable us to make changes to that bit.

The example question at least demonstrates citation by example; it's part of why I configured it to that one specifically  during my time as a diamond.

Comment: So maybe we should primarily use [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) or [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) link in the relevant comments instead of the tour?

Comment: I'm not sure what comments you mean, but we can link to the tour _and also_ other pages.

Answer (score 4):

#### There is a help article dedicated to this, and we have our own guidance we can link.

[How do I write a good answer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Link this article if you feel the need to leave more detailed guidance about writing good answers that is not covered in the tour.

We also have our [citation expectation meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-rpg-stack-exchange) that is even better and more specific than the help article. I prefer to leave a link to this.

Comment: If there is a dedicated help article, why do we leave links to the tour below unacceptable answers?

Comment: @enkryptor I typically leave links to the [tour], the [help] and if I think it is necessary, I leave a link to our [citation expectation meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-rpg-stack-exchange). So I can't really speak for "we".

Comment: @enkryptor I link to the tour for new users and for people who seem to not get how the site works. I also follow it up with more specific advice and links to meta if needed. If an answer has clear articulatable problems not covered by the tour, and someone's _only_ linking to the tour in response, they might be dropping the ball just a bit.

Answer (score 3):

### The tour is only a *basic* introduction to the site

The tour gives a basic, high level introduction to the site. And it's hard to give an actually useful definition of what a good answer is, especially that fits into a place like the tour. That fits better into the help center, and for any aspects which aren't covered by the (non-editable) articles there, meta.

At risk of suggesting others just copy me, I usually link to both the tour and the help center. For convenience, note that `[tour]` and `[help]` are magic links to the tour and help center respectively. And if there are *specific* issues in a post, describing those (and linking to a help article or meta on the topic) are more useful in general.

Comment: `[ask]` and `[answer]` links I often put into a welcome message = they are magic links to the how to ask a question help articles. Here is [an example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/189323/what-does-it-mean-for-a-spell-component-to-be-consumed/189329#comment510478_189329)