# Workshopping "What is the best way to bring a campaign to an end?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, dnd-5e, workshop-question

I've recently posted the question [What is the best way to bring a campaign to an end?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204360/62294) on the Role-Playing Games Stack Exchange, but it was closed because it ended up seeming too broad or just phrased weird.

I am having a hard time narrowing down the question to a singular problem. Should I just stick with the end question of "Is boredom a valid reason to end a campaign?"? Or is that also too much of an opinion-based question?

What could I do to improve it and allow it to actually be a question that can be answered? I want to narrow down the question so it's less opinion-based and more focused, but cannot for the life of me figure out how.

I'm really hoping that I can get the question re-opened, because I'm pretty sure the answers would be really helpful for me later on.

### Current version of the Question

> This is mainly just a question I decided to ask out of curiosity because sometimes I can get bored of a campaign and I wouldn't want to end it because the players could still be enjoying themselves. The players have mentioned they liked combat scenes but would appreciate more opportunities for them to express their characters with role-play. With being a very inexperienced DM I know next to nothing about good ways to add changes to the campaign.

> I'm currently just playing in the Eberron world with a homebrew questline and I don't really have a fully set idea what the players should strive for. (mainly because I cannot think of anything enjoyable)

> I don't really want to end the campaign but with no new ideas coming into my head to spice up how the game is played it's really hard to bring back the enjoyment from when the campaign felt fresh and new.

> For me, the combat appears to drag on too much and that limits opportunity for roleplay. I have discussed with the players and gotten mixed responses. Some like the combat and some want more roleplay.

> As DM, I would like more roleplay - but I also want all players to be happy. How can I adjust my campaign to do this?

Comment: Rather than starting with your question, can you also give us a summary of the problem you yourself are experiencing. We see your final question, but we have no details as to what's leading to it. The answer to all of your questions is "maybe" because of a lack of details. You give us the details of your specific problem and that will help us narrow it down and actually give you a specific solution. But right now, you've got several questions - each of which would be a separate question with a separate answer.

Comment: @NautArch less a *would* but more a *could* be one. Depending on the details, they might interlock more or less, resulting in a more clear answer. Some *general* answers like "your toolbox is bigger than TPK" is possible in the current state, just as much as "You do what is best for you."

Comment: Maybe? But we don’t really know and we’ve got several questions that should really be asked on their own. All four of those questions deserve their own focus.

Comment: Asking if boredom (or just about anything else) is a "valid reason" for ending a campaign is a lot like asking us, this stack, for permission to end your campaign.  I don't think any variation on that will fly-- first, you don't need permission, second, it begs the question of what reasons are "valid" and is going to be opinion based.

Comment: There might be an answerable question in the story/narrative aspects of satisfactory endings to a game.  If I can think of enough meat for that bone, I might try to turn it into an answer here in meta, but I'm not sure that I can.  (Others are encouraged to do so, if that thought sparks an answer from someone else.)

Comment: "*Is boredom a valid reason for a DM to want to end a campaign?*" realistically, what would you do if somebody answered "No"? Would you continue the campaign, despite your growing dissatisfaction with it? Would you search for a "valid" reason to end the campaign? That's dancing around the issue. Or [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you do not want to continue a campaign, ask how to do that. If you foresee the campaign's end coming ahead but you're not sure how to handle it - ask for that instead.

Comment: As currently written this is a discussion prompt.

Comment: ahh sorry a lot of things were changed and i forgot to update the meta question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up from what I've observed of the community standards here,  this is a single-issue question and answer site where discrete (Single issue) questions that can have an answer backed by supporting evidence (Books/references for points of fact, specific anecdotes with how it helped solve the problem at hand for subjective help, see [subjective questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/how-do-we-ask-and-answer-subjective-questions) and [citations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696))

The scope of the question,  while more supporting evidence for the situation you are in can be useful, the actual question should be a discrete, single answer question.  The idea is for this site to be a repository for future users to be able to search for answers that have already been given,  so having each question focus on one thing is best.

So,  let's look at the things that could be converted into questions and note before you actually ask them, you should search to see if they already have answers (as some are common things)

> I'm currently just playing in the Eberron world with a homebrew questline and I don't really have a fully set idea what the players should strive for. (mainly because I cannot think of anything enjoyable)

"What are some ways to integrate hooks to a homebrew quest to get their characters involved in roleplay?" is how I would phrase it.  I'm new here though, so if someone has a better phrasing, I'm up to changing it! same with all the future suggesitons

> I don't really want to end the campaign but with no new ideas coming into my head to spice up how the game is played it's really hard to bring back the enjoyment from when the campaign felt fresh and new.

I'd look up things on "DM burnout",  there is likely material there.  If not,  a question of the sort of "What are some ways to restore DM interest in a campaign after the beginning?"  Here you might get DMs telling you how they dealt with it in the past.

> For me, the combat appears to drag on too much and that limits opportunity for roleplay. I have discussed with the players and gotten mixed responses. Some like the combat and some want more roleplay.

What are ways I could speed up combat?

> As DM, I would like more roleplay - but I also want all players to be happy. How can I adjust my campaign to do this?

"How can I balance a mixed table where some prefer more combat and some prefer more roleplay?"

Note each of these should be its own question...and before you run with them, I'd wait until some of the actual long time members of the community confirm that my suggestions are good :).

Finally,  So, the opening "What is the best way to..." Some of these questions are considered good/on topic here...if it could be answered with some form of specific reasoning why. Examples per Thomas Markov: "eat cheese cake" would be an opinion, whereas "to cook a cheese cake when I only have access to a 55 gallon drum and a welding torch" is something that people with experience can provide useful information on. The latter is acceptable here.

P.S. Speaking purely as myself as a mathematician I would prefer the more technically correct "What is an optimal way to..." to "The best way to",  since there can be more than one optimal solution. Even more pedantically, a mathematician would prefer "maximal" as in mathematics "optimum" implies uniqueness.  However, in English, it can be accepted usage to say there is "more than one optimal solution". That's not the community standard here though,  so please treat this final paragraph as a minor bit of pedantry that can be safely ignored.

Comment: *"this is an objective fact based question and answer site where discrete (Single issue) questions that can have an objective (not subjective) answer backed by supporting evidence."* - The only correct part of this statement is the "single issue" bit. See these meta posts for guidance concerning subjective questions and answers: [How do we ask and answer subjective questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3204) , [What are the citation expectations of answers on RPG Stack Exchange?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov One of the main reasons I wrote up this answer (in addition to there not being one) was to test my understanding here.  Those links were very helpful, I updated my answer accordingly.  Does it now meet community standards?

Comment: I disagree with you second paragraph. Asking "what is the best way to *blank*?" is not the problem, it is whatever gets put into *blank* that is the problem. We have numerous question framed as "what is the best way", both objective and subjective questions. If it so happened that the specific problem you were having with your cheesecake could be solved with cheese whiz, and the reason I know this is because I have had the same problem, and was able to successfully solve it with cheese whiz, then an answer explaining that would be a valuable contribution. ...(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) .. But the difference there is *specific problem*. "What's the best way to eat cheese cake" is just an opinion poll, and you are correct to point out that it is a problematic sort of question. But, "what is the best way to cook a cheese cake when I only have access to a 55 gallon drum and a welding torch" is a very specific problem that begins with "what is the best way to".

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Edited again to include your examples and put my minor pedantry as a post script clearly marked.